# ProFTPD with AWS IAM and Cognito Auth

Tags: authentication, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam, amazon-cognito, proftpd

I'm looking for any implementation or someone that has used IAM and Cognito to authentication in a ProFTPD server in EC2.
Is there anyone that has done it?

Comment: Do you mean using IAM/Cognito as the authentication mechanism for clients attempting to log into a ProFTPD server, or something else?

Comment: It is exactly what I mean.

Comment: I don't think such an implementation exists _yet_.  However, if you ask this question on the ProFTPD mailing lists (or the `#proftpd` IRC channel on freenode.net), the ensuing discussion (about specifics, use cases, _etc_) might lead to such work being done.

Comment: Feel free to contact me directly (tj@castaglia.org) to talk more about this, as I suspect it will require custom module development (rather than having a "solution" to be posted on StackOverflow here).